# Java Object.finalize() vs. C# IDisposable

Tags: java, c#, destructor, finalizer, finalize

I have extensive `Java` experience and know why `finalize()` is scheduled for a removal soon. On the other hand, my knowledge about `C#` is skin-deep - I am more or less aware about what features it offers on the abstract level, but no real experience to speak of. Some time ago I have found a solution looking for a problem and from a search of languages which support `C++`-like destructors came `IDisposable` in CLI.

What are the differences which make the latter a continually supported feature?

Comment: FYI C# has finalizers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers

Comment: FWIW, declaring finalizers in C# are also discouraged (you really should be using safe handles if you really need that).

Comment: I've only just briefly read some things on `IDisposable`, but my impression is that the equivalent in Java is the `AutoCloseable` interface, not the `Object.finalize()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, really, they're not the same.

Java's `finalize()` has a direct equivalent in C#'s finalizers (declared as `~T()`, where `T` is the class name). Use of finalizers in C# is heavily discouraged now in modern code, due to how tricky they are to get right in practice. Maybe they'll get deprecated too some day. In the meantime, if you really need that kind of behaviour, you really should be using safe handles.

Compared to finalizers, `IDisposable` seems to provide automatic and deterministic cleanup of resources, like C++'s destructors. That's neat! But I said *seems*, because actually `IDisposable` is not magic. On its own, it does nothing. What you really mean is the `using` statement, which is really just syntactic sugar for a `try`/`finally` statement that calls `Dispose()` in the `finally` part (with some null checking for good measure).

```
using var x = new T();
// ...
```

Java also has that, with the `AutoCloseable` interface and "try-with-resources" idiom:

```
try (T x = new T()) {
    // ...
}
```

However `IDisposable` and `using` have been introduced much earlier relatively in the language's lifespan compared to "try-with-resources" (C# 2.0 vs Java 7), so their presence is more pervasive across both the standard library and third party libraries.